# How to change default value of dropdownButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

I`m creating a dropdown button in flutter, but i have a problem
when i use dropdown it shows the name of the **first item** but i want to change it(default value) to **categories** and idk how to do that, also i tried to use hint(as you see in codes)but it didn't work.
here is my codes:

```
Container(
            height: pageHeight / 15,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child:DropdownButton(
                value: _value,
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("First Item"),
                    value: 1,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Second Item"),
                    value: 2,
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _value = value as int ;
                  });
                },
                hint:Text("Select item")
            ),
          )
```

[image]

I want to change this **First Item** to **categories**

Comment: Can you please be clearer?

Comment: share extra code and what do you exact want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make value nullable. `DropdownButton` can have null value and while it is null it will show `hint` widget.

```
  int? _value;
```

```
DropdownButton(
                  value: _value,
                  items: const [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("First Item"),
                      value: 1,
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Second Item"),
                      value: 2,
                    ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value = value as int;
                    });
                  },
                  hint: Text("categories"),
                ),
```

Comment: that's right my value was : `int? _value=1;`

Comment: Yap it was having initial value as 1, that why you were always having 1st item as selected.

Comment: Exception occured. `Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 888 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)`

Comment: @DevConductor can you share the link of your question?

Comment: @Md. Yeasin Sheikh. Thanks for your reply. I fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Asign on initState()

selectedDropDownValue = "categories";

```
Container(
            height: pageHeight / 15,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child:DropdownButton(
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("First Item"),
                    value: 1,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Second Item"),
                    value: 2,
                  ),
                ],
                value: selectedDropDownValue, 
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDropDownValue = value;
                  });
                },
                hint:Text("Select item")
            ),
          )
```